# beautiful soup get table after specific header

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I position BS4 to start with the table after `<h3>64-bit deb for Ubuntu/Debian</h3>`? There are lots of tables and the only distinct is the  header.

```
<h3>Windows 64-bit</h3>
<table width="600" border="1" align="center">
:
</table>
:
<h3>64-bit deb for Ubuntu/Debian</h3>
<table width="600" border="1" align="center">
:
</table>
:
```

Comment: Getting the specific table with an index wouldn't be convinient?

Comment: The table is a dump from an internal software repo very messy, but I can control the <h3>what to write here</h3> so I like to aggregate lots of directories into one large file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```py
>>> for header in soup.find_all('h3'):
...     if header.get_text() == '64-bit deb for Ubuntu/Debian':
...         header.find_next_sibling()
...
<table align="center" border="1" width="600">
:
</table>
```

Comment: "@political scientist" that worked. I tried `.next_sibling()`but `.find_next_sibling()` worked

Answer (score 2):

bs4 4.7.1 + you can use `:contains` with adjacent sibling (+) combinator. No need for a loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<h3>Windows 64-bit</h3>
<table width="600" border="1" align="center">
:
</table>
:
<h3>64-bit deb for Ubuntu/Debian</h3>
<table width="600" border="1" align="center">
:'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('h3:contains("64-bit deb for Ubuntu/Debian") + table')
```